# tkinter window will not pop up

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

I am doing a project with tkinter. I've recently switched to linux Mint on my computer. The program runs fine with no errors, the gui just won't come up. I'm using pycharm.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

THEME_COLOR = "#375362"

class QuizInterface:
    def __int__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Quizzler")
        self.window.config(padx=30, pady=30)

        self.card = Canvas(width=300, height=250)
        self.card.create_text(text="Question goes here", font=("arial", 20, "italic"))
        self.card.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)


        self.score = Label(text="Score: ", font=("arial", 13, "bold"))
        self.score.grid(row=0, column=1)

        true_image = PhotoImage(file="images/true.png")
        self.true_button = Button(image=true_image, highlightthickness=0)

        false_image = PhotoImage(file="images/false.png")
        self.f_button = Button(image=false_image, highlightthickness=0)

        self.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you actually instantiate `QuizInterface`? Because that's not in your code snippet.

Comment: i did, it gets called in my main.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the function that gets called when a class is intitialized is `__init__`, but you are defining `def __int__(self):`, so:

```
class QuizInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```